# Showing orthogonal matrix for $\left\langle {u,v} \right\rangle = \left\langle {Au,Av} \right\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, orthogonal-matrices

Show the $A$ is a orthogonal matrix when the $A$ satisfying $\left\langle {u,v} \right\rangle  = \left\langle {Au,Av} \right\rangle$, $\forall u, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (The $A$ is a $3 \times3$ matrix.)

My book proved it by showing  $A^tA = I$ But I solved the above question by different ways comparing my text book solution. The problem is I can't sure my solution is exact or not. Let me suggest my solution.

> condition) $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = \langle Ae_i, Ae_j\rangle $.

The $Ae_i$ is a $i$ th column of the $A$, $i$ th column and $j$ th column orthogonal each other if the $i \neq j$.

But if the $i=j$, $1= \langle e_i, e_i\rangle= \langle Ae_i, Ae_i\rangle$ (I.e. $\Vert Ae_i \Vert =1$ )

So all the norm of the $i$ th column of the $A$ is $1$

Consequently, Column of the $A$ are orthonormal. It is orthogonal matrix.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Your proof looks good to me and I would guess the book used the exact same method to reach the conclusion $A^t A = I$.

Comment: @Christoph Or they could've used the implicit definition / fundamental property of the transpose ($\langle A^tx,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle$ for all $x,y$). That also leads to the same result, and seems more textbooky to me.

Comment: Wow four different people edited. You have a great question.